# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL - only on my file

Tags: jquery

I'm getting this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

can anybody help why?

Comment: Post your code.  Nobody is going to download something from a dropbox link.  That link will be dead within a month, and your question will then be useless for all who follow.

Comment: yes,but the code is ok,it's something local because I copy the code from jsfiddle,sorry.

Comment: @Brad I agree but to be fair we wouldn't have seen the problem if he had copied the code here (see my answer).

Comment: @dystroy: Then it is not a question suitable for Stack Overflow, which is a repository of questions about programming languages and _not_ a free-for-all debugging crowdsource tool.

Answer (score 2):

You have an invisible bad character at the end of script.js, probably because you copied some code from jsfiddle.

Remove it with your favorite editor : go at the end of the script.js file and use the backspace key : you'll see your cursor remove at the same space at one time because the char you remove is U+200B, the zero width space.

This problem is due to a bug of their script editor, probably [this one](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-docs-alpha/issues/163).