# Random coloured words in a H1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to have each word in a H1 a random colour and that if you refresh the page these will then be randomised again?

I have 5 set colours I want to use. How would I code this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I would have each letter in the <h1> tag be surrounded by a <span>.  Set the style of each <span> to have a random color.  You can do this easily with a javascript/jquery loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's possible :

```
var colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'black'];
$('h1').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).text().split(' ').map(function(v){
        return '<span style="color:'+colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]+'">'+v+'</span>';
    }).join(' '));
});​​​​​​
```

The main idea is to split the content of each h1 into words and replace the words by embedding them in `<span>` as you can't style a word but only an element.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/xRbzH/)

Comment: Nice solution, incredibly ugly in practice but that isn't the point lol.

Comment: AMAZING thanks a lot for the reply and demo, really appreciate it

Comment: one last thing...

i seem to be havin an issue with this code can u see the issue?

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
var colors = ['#ffc200', '#1e97f4', '#1ebb70', '#f1004a', '#ff6ddd'];
$('h1').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).text().split(' ').map(function(v){
        return '<span style="color:'+colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]+'">'+v+'</span>';
    }).join(' '));
});
}

Comment: As you have jQuery, I'd suggest the use of `$(function(){...})` which is additive. But can you make a fiddle with the code that doesn't work ?

Comment: What's your issue ? I'm sorry but I don't get your last comments.

Comment: you suggested the use of $(function(){..}) but in the code i pasted in the above comment its already there. can u modify my code so i can see what it should be like please?

Comment: `$(function(){...})` is a replacement for `window.onload=function(){}` (not exactly the same, the function is called when the dom is ready).

Comment: ahhh ok... sorry for the confusion
Is there a way to modify the code so that all colours are always used on each refresh? currently some colours dont get used and some get used too much

Comment: If you copied your code from jsfiddle into your editor, you may have [an invisible character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554140/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal-only-on-my-file). I've put inline a working example for you : http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/randomColorsInH1.html

Comment: Fantastic, again... much appreciated :)