# Change color randomly

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph or div.

HTML

```
<p style="color:red;">Change color randomly</p>
```

this code will show the

[image]

but I want this type of output using CSS any idea

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can add span tags in between , then add css color property

Comment: Randomly according to a timer, each letter a different colour, or just a random colour from a list?

Comment: this is what you want.
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671039/random-coloured-words-in-a-h1

Comment: @yasir hashmi  you are right but i want this using CSS. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use HTML/CSS to make it look like what you have in your example but if you want it to change after the page has loaded, you need JavaScript.

Comment: No it cant be achieve by only CSS, you must use javascript OR you have to type each color between words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this with pure CSS where it's really random, you'll need some JavaScript for that. I created a little demo that also uses jQuery & it generates different colours each time you reload the page.

**HTML**

```
<p>Change color randomly</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Define some colours
var colours = [
    "red",
    "orange",
    "yellow",
    "green",
    "blue",
    "purple"    
];

// Retrieve the words
var text = $("p").html().split(" ");

// Empty the elment
$("p").empty();

// Iterate over the words
$.each(text, function(i, word) {
    if(i != text.length) {
        word += " "; // Add space after word 
    }

     // Get random color
    var colourIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);

    $("<span>")
        .html(word)
        .css("color", colours[colourIndex])
        .appendTo($("p"));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmHpt/).

Comment: Here's a little [update of the script](http://jsfiddle.net/mmHpt/1/) which uses the random hex color code snippet **Victor** suggested, so you don't have an array of fixed colours and it will be _really_ random.

Answer (score 1):

There is direct pseudo class to style the `first-letter` but not the first word, so you need to add any inline elements to get it styled.

Use `nth-child` with `span` tag

```
<p style="color:red;"><span>Change</span> color <span>randomly</span></p>

span:nth-child(1){
    color:green
}
span:nth-child(2){
    color:violet
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EVKJ2/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS is not possible. You will have to use Javascript to code this feature. Here is a link that probably helps you to get started: http://paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

Below css will do it.

```
<p style="color:red;"><span style="color:#909">Change</span> color <span style="color:blue">randomly</span></p>
```