# How to make my letters change colors periodically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make the inner html of a div to change colors. My div looks like this

```
<div class = 'child'>     
    <span class="color">F</span>
    <span class="color">u</span>
    <span class="color">n</span>
    <span class="color">n</span>
    <span class="color">y</span>
    <span class="color"> </span>
    <span class="color">k</span>
    <span class="color">l</span>
    <span class="color">o</span>
    <span class="color">k</span> 
</div>
```

and my javascript looks like this

```
var value = document.getElementsByClassName("child")[0].innerHTML;

bannerArray = value.split("");

var colourArray = [
  "rgb(248, 116, 138)",
  "rgb(248, 125, 145)",
  "rgb(248, 140, 160)",
  "rgb(248, 160, 180)",
  "rgb(248, 175, 195)",
  "pink",
  "rgb(248, 195, 215)",
  "rgb(248, 205, 235)",
  "rgb(248, 225, 225)",
];


for  ( let i = 0; i < colourArray.length; i++) {
  
  for ( let j  = 0; j < bannerArray.length; j++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("color")[j].style.color = colourArray[i];
  }
}
```

the result of that code is basically every letter in the banner array gets the first color from the color array, then the second color, until i end up with all the letters being the last color ie rgb(248, 225, 225).
What id like is the first color to pass through the first letter, then move to the second letter, then have the first letter take the second color in the color array, then the second color to move to the second letter, then the first letter to take the third color in the array and so on and so forth like marque for lack of a better description, So very sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: This is pretty well explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129796/change-color-randomly   
Hope it helps

Comment: thx let me take a look, i swear ive googled for two days now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use setTimeout

Get all the children (`spans`) of div with the class `child` into an array

> I suggest using `id` instead. If there is another div with the same class `child` above this div. The first div ends up getting the styles.

```
const children = document.querySelector(".child").children;
```

Define a function to apply color to the characters

```
function applyColors(children, colorArr) {
   for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      children[i].style.color = colorArr[i];
   }
}
```

Write a function to rotate your colors array. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23368052/14853666)

```
function arrayRotate(arr, reverse) {
  if (reverse) arr.unshift(arr.pop());
  else arr.push(arr.shift());
  return arr;
}
```

Clone your colors array as a best practice. ( As you keep changing this array in the next step )

```
const changingColorsArray = [...colourArray];
```

Change the color of characters every 1s (1000ms) and apply the same to your characters.

> Call the function for one time outside setInterval to apply colors on page load.

```
// apply colors on page load
applyColors(children, changingColorsArray);

setInterval(() => {
  // change colors
  arrayRotate(changingColorsArray, true);

  // apply colors
  applyColors(children, changingColorsArray);
}, 1000);
```

Note: You need to add one more color to your colourArray as there are 10 characters including   in the middle

PS: use `const or let` over `var`

Check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sof-changing-colors-q6fve4?file=/src/index.js:702-932) for a working demo

Comment: Thanks a lot bruv, i managed to use an additional function to change the value of reverse every time the color arrays first item got put in its last index.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/starting-template-forked-hg9oso?file=/src/App.tsx

by using the hsl colors, you can easily run through color wheel and set the different hue for every letter :) I hope it helps :)

p.s. you can use whatever you want instead of counter for changing the color position...